# Why is there に in 頭痛に障る？

Tags: grammar

> ……溜息をつくだけでも、頭痛に障る…。

Is there an explanation for this に or is it just like 触る which can be used with both に and を ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

障る is an uncommon **intransitive** verb which is used in the form ～に障る and means "to do harm to ～", "to negatively affect ～" or "to disturb ～." Unlike 触る, there is no transitive usage "～を障る". (～の)気に障る is a relatively common set phrase that means "to annoy/irritate someone."

> - お酒を飲みすぎると健康に障りますよ。
> - 連日の徹夜は体に障る。
> - 気に障ったら申し訳ありません。
> - 明日の仕事に障るといけないので、今日は帰ります。

So 頭痛に障る should mean "my (chronic) headache will be worsened (only by sighing)". I think this usage is fine, but as l'électeur said in the comment, ～に障る is much more commonly used with generic words like 健康.

Answer (score 1):

It's a completely different verb from 触る. It means "to be harmful to" or "to interfere with" depending on the context. It's intransitive, so を would not be expected.

Basically you have "even just sighing makes my headache worse."

Here are some example sentences.

[http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/障る](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E9%9A%9C%E3%82%8B)

Comment: `It's a completely different verb from 触る`と言うところは質問者の意味を理解していないと思います。意味的に「触る」はヲかニの助詞を使える動詞で、障るはそれと同じ様に二つの助詞は可能である動詞ですかと言う質問。

Comment: He seems to be expecting を to be the default, and I don't really see why, so that part of the question doesn't seem all that relevant with the two verbs being unrelated.

Comment: I assume he sees を as the default for all Japanese verbs, but he is aware of 触る being able to alternately accept に.

Answer (score 1):

sawaru is intransitive v. so it requires 'ni' particle